# Restoring force of electron-nucleus spring model (Lorentz oscillator model)

Tags: optics, speed-of-light, harmonic-oscillator, refraction, non-linear-optics

The restoring force should fulfill at least two criterion

1. Experience repulsive force when it is compressed and  attractive force when it is extended
2. The restoring force always increases with distance from equilibrium position.

However, the Lorentz oscillator model does not fulfill both of the criterion

1. We have electron and positive charged nucleus, the force is always attractive when it is extended or compressed
2. When it is extended, the coulomb force is getting weaker because distance between electron and nucleus increases, where the restoring force must increase with distance.

What is the correct explanation?

Comment: The "correct explanation" would be quantum theory applied to this problem.  So I'm not sure what you're asking here by "correct explanation".

Comment: How quantum theory explain the origin of refractive index? Photon interferes itself?

Answer (score 1):

Careful -- by this argument, you might wonder why the electron stays at a finite distance from its parent nucleus at all!  The answer is (classically at least) that the electron is orbiting the nucleus as well as being attracted to it.  As a result, its effective potential energy curve in the radial direction actually has a minimum, about which it can oscillate harmonically, if the displacement is small enough.  Hence we can say small displacements to the electron can be treated like a mass on a spring.

Comment: If an electron orbits the nucleus, then moving the electron away from the nucleus would force it to escape from its orbit, right? Instead of expericncing a stronger restoring force

Comment: Not necessarily -- if it's a small displacement then there will in fact be a restoring force back to the equilibrium radius.  This is to do with the fact that there are *two* forces on the electron in its frame of reference:

the attractive Coulomb force, which indeed decreases as $1/r$, and also

the "repulsive" centrifugal force, which for constant angular momentum actually decreases faster as $1/r^2$.

Again this is a classical treatment, Quantum considerations are sure to change this, but it's a good classical model nonetheless.

Comment: thanks for your answer! So if I understand it correctly, the centrifugal force decreases if the electron moves away from the nucleus; this decreases faster than the Coulomb force; therefore the net force is more towards the nucleus than before

Comment: Yep, as long as the displacement is small.